# Node Red Sensor Output: How to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: node-red

Just beginning my adventures using Node Red and my Raspberry Pi 3. Have a DHT-22 temp and humidity sensor both properly outputting using the debug tab, and also properly displaying in gauges on the UI. Would like to alter the temperature's node's code to translate the Celsius reading into Fahrenheit. The following is the code as it currently exists:

```
if(msg.topic === "rpi-dht22")
{
msg.payload = (msg.payload + "* C")
}
return msg
```

I was thinking (as an absolute neophyte) that I could try the following, but it of course doesn't work:

```
if(msg.topic === "dpi-dht22")
{
msg.payload = (("msg.payload" * 9/5 +32) + "* F")
}
return msg
```

**Update: I think I've found the cleanest and most logical fix by creating a filter function and placing it between the sensor and the gauge:

```
if(msg.topic === "rpi-dht22")
{
    val = msg.payload
    f = (val*1.8) + 32
    ;
}
{
    msg.payload = parseFloat(f).toFixed(1) + " °F"}
return msg
```

Comment: Try removing the quotes around `"msg.payload"` on line 3 of your second block

Comment: Try int(msg.payload)

Comment: Or if that doesn’t work, be a lot more specific what you mean by “doesn’t work”.

Comment: Sincere thanks for everyone's responses. I tried int(msg.payload) to no avail; it was still returning the celsius value. Nonetheless, I discovered an even simpler fix: I edited the "value" field of the temperature gauge node to                                        {{value * 9/5 +32}} and everything ended up working as needed. I haven't learned how to fix using proper code on the front-end of this flow yet, but at least I have the desired result. Again, sincere thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(msg.topic === "rpi-dht22")
{val = msg.payload f = (val*1.8) + 32;
}
{msg.payload = parseFloat(f).toFixed(1) + " °F"}
return msg
```